# Are there any ELMAH-like exception-logging FOSS packages?

Tags: language-agnostic, exception, elmah

Are there any [ELMAH](https://code.google.com/archive/p/elmah/)- or [crashkit](http://crashkitapp.appspot.com/)-like exception-logging FOSS packages?

Specifically, these are exception-logging applications; the code you write pushes exception reports to these systems so they can be logged, grouped, searched, and acted-upon. Both apps help with the approach of [Exception Driven Development](https://blog.codinghorror.com/exception-driven-development/) (not a fan of the phrase, but I *do* like the idea of a centralised way to collect exceptions into a monitoring system).

I'm looking for an app that preferably:

- non-microsoft (inc. mono)
- language-agnostic, or
- has plugins for languages such as PHP, Python, etc
- can be hosted locally so I may hack for specific needs.

Is there anything out there like that at the moment? Or are ELMAH & crashkit the only options so far?

Comment: Always helps to explain what you're asking about for those of us who have k=no idea what ELMAH would be...

Answer (score 1):

There's Skidder for PHP: http://sourceforge.net/projects/skidder/
Also AVICODE for .NET: http://www.avicode.com/
And Exceptioneer for Winforms: http://exceptioneer.com/Public/Demonstration.aspx

I'm not seeing much else out there other than what you've already mentioned.